# Insufficient disk space to repair master file table (MFT) mirror

Tags: chkdsk, mft

I borrowed an empty 500GB Toshiba HDD from a friend of mine. I have a 1 TB HDD installed in my laptop which I needed to clone to the new 500GB HDD. I quick formatted the drive 500GB HDD just to be sure. I tried cloning from EaseUS Todo Backup, it ran for like 10 minutes and gave me a "Failed to write Sector" error. I tried again with AOMEI Backupper and it gave me the same error. Then I tried "CHKDSK H: /r" on 500 GB HDD. All 5 stages were completed but it the end it gave me this error even though the HDD was completely empty

```
Stage 5: Looking for bad, free clusters ...
122056231 free clusters processed.
Free space verification is complete.
Correcting errors in the Master File Table (MFT) mirror.
Insufficient disk space to repair master file table (MFT) mirror.
CHKDSK aborted.
```

I tried a few S.M.A.R.T programs and they all showed no problems with the HDD. What can be wrong? Can i fix the Master File Table by full formatting the 500GB drive? Can i use it then?

Comment: Format which storage device?  If you format your 500 Gb you won't be able to clone your data to the 1 TB drive because you would have **deleted** the data because of the format.  Your question isn't clear, you should edit your question, and clarify it

Comment: Done. I basically need to clone my 1 TB HDD (installed in my laptop) to the empty 500 GB HDD. The empty drive is giving me the problems i described above. Can i fix the MFT by full formatting the 500 GB HDD?

Comment: May be cleaning with diskpart command solves it.

Comment: @Biswa How to do that?

Comment: Yes, formatting the drive, and recreating the partition would solve any potential MFT issues.  Data on the drive would obviously be lost.

Comment: @AntiSaby How you do that is well [documented](http://knowledge.seagate.com/articles/en_US/FAQ/005929en?language=en_US)

Comment: is by any chance the "Failed to write sector" related to corrupted MFT?

Answer (score 2):

My first answer was deleted as I hadn't quite solved this problem, but now that I have, maybe the answer will pass muster and be of some help. Had the same issue on the 1st of a dual boot disk system and after running chkdsk /f /r a couple of times it failed with the error listed and also made the OS unbootable. I make Macrium Reflect images in case a glitch comes along that can't be fixed, but restoring the last image made a month ago still did not fix the problem. Also, ran chkdsk /f /r on the 1st drive from the alternate boot disk and got the same error: the MFT could not be fixed. What finally worked was booting a Windows 7 repair disk and running chkdsk /f /r from the DOS prompt. I'd tried this before but for some reason the CD malfunctioned. So,if you get the error "Insufficient disk space to repair master file table (MFT) mirror" running chkdsk /r, it might very well work to run it from the DOS prompt booted with a Windows repair disk.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i fixed it. Full formatting the 500 GB HDD(which took ~4 hours) worked. I was able to clone the 1 TB HDD to 500 GB HDD.

Comment: My 1 TB HDD took 5 seconds to full format with [gparted](https://gparted.org/). You had only to format HDD.